# Count white space characters in Java

Tags: java

Hi all I currently have a program which is supposed to count only the white spaces but the program I have seems to be counting everything can someone identify whats missing or in the wrong place?

```
public class SpaceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(SpaceCounter.class.getResourceAsStream("Test")) .useDelimiter("\\s"); // imports the text file and uses delimiter to count the spaces
        int counter1 = 0; //sets 1st counter 1

        while (scan.hasNextLine()) { // while loop
            scan.next(); // scanner goes onto next line
            counter1++; 
        }
        System.out.println("this file contains this amount of spaces: " + counter1);
   }
}
```

Comment: put one condition to check space. and increment that counter inside that if condition

Comment: Do you want to count empty lines?

Comment: would the condition go before the counter or would it go elsewhere

Comment: and yes thorbjorn ravn andersen I would like it to count the empty lines

Answer (score 1):

```
  int spaceCount = 0;
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()) {
         if (c == ' ') {
         spaceCount++;
    }
  }
```

you can achieve it like this

Answer (score 0):

change your while loop and code as below :

```
while (scan.hasNextLine()){ // while loop
     String s= scan.next(); // scanner goes onto next line
     counter1 += s.length() - s.replaceAll(" ", "").length();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count the amount of spaces in text, and you *really* want to use `Scanner` for this, you can use something like this:

```
public class SpaceCounter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(SpaceCounter.class.getResourceAsStream("Test")).useDelimiter("\\S*");
        int counter1 = 0;
        while (scan.hasNext()) {
            scan.next();
            counter1++; 
        }

        System.out.println("this file contains this amount of spaces: " +  counter1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use something like:

```
// FIRST OF ALL: Delete the .useDelimiter("\\s") from your Scanner
while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scan.nextLine();

  if (line.isEmpty()) {
    counter1++;
  } else {
    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
      if (Character.isWhitespace(line.charAt(i))) {
        counter1++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```